# Check if a datetime is in daylight saving in SQL

Tags: sql-server

In C# there is a build in method **IsDaylightSavingTime** which allows returns a bool value indicating if the date that is being passed falls in the range of daylight saving. I would like to know if there is something similar in SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about running the CLR on SQL Server and directly leverage the .Net Framework [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382013.aspx) type through a [CLR scalar-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx)?

In order to help SQLServer choose the best possible execution plan, do not forget to carefully value the [SqlFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.aspx) attribute. For instance, if your function only wraps the call to **IsDaylightSavingTime**, you'd better decorate it this way.

```
[SqlFunction(
     DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, 
     SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None,
     IsDeterministic = true,
     IsPrecise = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little bit late. But this script worked fine for me:

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()

declare @IsDaylightSaving bit
declare @tz int = DATEPART(TZOFFSET, @date AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time')

set @IsDaylightSaving = case when @tz = -420 then 1 else 0 end
select @IsDaylightSaving
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**